# How to highlight present speaking text in android for epub text in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, epub

I am using webview to render epub data and able to display the data and implement text to speech functionality to the text ! Now i want to highlight the present reading text in webview! for that i tried to use like

```
webview.findall(...);
webview.setSelected(true);
webview.findNext(true);
```

But no use !!

Comment: Try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910041/android-highlight-text-in-webview-above-android-version-4-0-3

Comment: if you find the solution then please inform  me.Thanks in advance